# Spreading new EventEmitter into object drops emitter methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

const spread = { ...emitter };

console.log(spread.on); // undefined
console.log(emitter.on); // [Function: addListener]
```

Why does spreading drop this method? And how can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does spreading drop this method?

Because [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) only copies **own, enumerable properties** from the target. It doesn't copy inherited properties, and it doesn't copy the prototype of the object.

I'm not sure that you can clone an `EventEmitter`, but if you can it's not going to be a simple one-liner. You'd have to create a new instance, get the events it has listeners for ([`eventNames`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emittereventnames)), then get the listeners for each event ([`listeners`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emitterlistenerseventname)), etc. And even then, some things are subclasses of `EventEmitter`...

Comment: `Object.assign` does copy prototype properties, so it solves this issue: `Object.assign(new EventEmitter(), { extraProp: true })`.

Comment: @AndyJessop - No, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) does what spread does: own, enumerable properties. That code works because you're assigning properties to something that is *already* an `EventEmitter` (`Object.assign` assigns to the first object, which it also returns). `ee = Object.assign(new EventEmitter(), { extraProp: true })` is the same as `ee = new EventEmitter(); ee.extraProp = true;`